# How to call a web api that has Oauth 2.0

Tags: c#, vb.net, oauth-2.0, webapi

Hi so we have an external web api we want to call to get data out. It is using oauth 2.0. Can somebody please explain how we would go about doing this in .NET either vb.net or c#. I have in the past created api, however this one seems very complicated. Firstly you have to be signed into their oauth web page they have which generates some cookies, using these cookies by syncing them up in postman we can see the data, however we need this to be within our .net app. Can somebody please help how we go about this. Some code would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: You should start by reading the OAuth specifications (https://oauth.net/2/).
The way to achieve this is roughly along these lines:
1. obtain the 3rd party oauth URL
2. create an endpoint on your http server that will receive the auth token
3. add the return url (pointing to your endpoint) to the oauth URL
4. fire up a web view (an embedded browser view) to the URL and wait for your enpoint to be triggered

Comment: Hi ok, so I realised that some of that was needed, however that does not tell me how. Like We have the oauth url, so how do we connect using c# or any other language. Then how do we use the token received to call the api url we have.

Comment: You don't "call" OAuth, the only way to make it work is to open a browser or webview and point it to that URL (which you modified to include your return address). Then the app waits until the backend gets called by the third party with an auth token. You save that token and notify the app. Then you make requests to your backend using that token.

Comment: First u try with PostMan agent which pass url and credentials or try Chilkat dll to get token. If u share some details is use full to find out.
If you try with Postman Agent, then u can get C# code from Postman Agent page itself,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how usually OAuth 2 authentication works.

You basically log in with username and password (optional second factor) and then you receive a token, the so called [Json Web Token](https://oauth.net/2/access-tokens/) or JWT (it holds encrypted information about your user, your access roles or groups you are member of as well as some timestamp which is the expiration time of the token).

In every subsequent request you make to the server, you pass this token in the request header (or in your case as cookie).

#### Example code:

Login request:

```
HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(_baseUrl, "token"));
string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    Username = _userName,
    Password = _password,
    secondFactor = secondFactor
});
httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    TokenResult r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResult>(responseContent);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.token))
    {
        _token = r.token;
        _tokenValidity = r.expirationDate;
        _refreshToken = r.refreshToken;
        _refreshTokenValidity = r.refreshTokenExpirationDate;
        return _token;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception($"Failed to get token from server.\r\n{responseContent}");
    }
}
```

Now you use the `_token` in subsequent requests in the request header:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);
using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(_baseUrl, relativePath));
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    stream.Position = 0;
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Please note, that usually the token has a certain lifetime after which it is basically useless. Some APIs offer a refresh token with which a new token can be requested without the user having to log in again with username and password, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

You said you have to use the token as cookie? Well there are APIs which work like this but personally I've never seen one like this, which is why I can't you help very much, but it shouldn't be much more than putting the token you got into a cookie with a certain name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For me this throws an error, because the second parameter of HttRequestMessage should be boolean, and "token" is not boolean.

Comment: Are you talking about the first line of code in the answer? The constructor of `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` has 3 overloads: An empty one, `public HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod method, Uri requestUri)` and finally `public HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod method, string requestUri)`. None of them accepts a boolean value. Please clarify what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking. I have a controller code where I use web api call to authenticate user. You can use your own model to pass the data. If your web api expects token for request, then you might have to get the token first to give a call to any method. Hope this helps.

```
 OktaUserDetailsModel Model = new OktaUserDetailsModel();
                Model.username = model.UserName;
                Model.password = model.Password;
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                   
                    HttpContent inputContent = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OktaAPIuri"], inputContent).Result;
                   
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        
                        string strResponse = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<string>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                        if (strResponse.ToUpper() == "TRUE")
                            return OktaSingleSignOnLogin(astrReturnUrl, model.UserName);
                        else
                            return ErrorPage();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       
                        return ErrorPage();
                    }
                }
```